# Is there any method to compare the angles of orientation of similar objects on a moving track?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to manipulate a robotic arm to pick and place objects on a moving track, the only thing coming to my mind is detecting the angle of which the object is placed so I can orient the gripper of the robot similarly. I have no problem with position detection.

Comment: What is your experience, where is your source code and what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried some contour detection using opencv on static images, I didn't find any clear method of getting the angle of orientation of each contour after detection or relate it to another known angle, so is there any way to do so?